# How would I perform arithmetic with field values from ArcGIS Pro and a variable in Python?

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-pro

Let's say I have a variable in a Python script:

```
myNum = 5
```

And I want to calculate all the values in my field by performing arithmetic with that that number(like +, -, /, etc. How would I do that? I'm thinking that you could do something like

```
arcpy.management.CalculateField(some_feature_class, some_field, expression)
```

But how would the expression parameter be formatted exactly? If this is even possible. I know that you can perform arithmetic on numeric values from ArcGIS Pro but is it possible to perform arithmetic with a variable from a Python script?

Comment: It is similar to ArcGIS desktop, you will need to use a python code block and set your value as a global. Read more about ArcGIS Pro expressions here: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-field-examples.htm If you're still confused I can answer with ArcGIS Desktop code and you can alter the minor differences between desktop and pro.

Comment: Since the OP never mentions updating the value of the variable, using `global` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is feasible in a codeblock using global values, here are some working examples from ArcGIS for Desktop which [from the help](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-field-examples.htm) are nearly identical to Pro. I am assuming you're wanting to do this in python but I will show the interactive form for a broader understanding.

The code for calculate a unique ascending number starting at a known value:

```
StartNumber = 25000
def CalcUniqueID():
    global StartNumber
    StartNumber += 1
    return StartNumber
```

Which looks like this in the form:

[image]

Adjusting by a set value is a similar concept:

```
Adjustment = 1000
def Increment(ExistingValue):
    global Adjustment
    if ExistingValue % 10:
        ExistingValue -= Adjustment
    else:
        ExistingValue += Adjustment
    return ExistingValue
```

Which looks like this in the form:

[image]

To do this in python code without the form:

```
# triple quotes to start and end, apart from that it's formatted exactly the same
CodeBlock ="""
Adjustment = 1000
def Increment(ExistingValue):
    global Adjustment
    if ExistingValue % 10:
        ExistingValue -= Adjustment
    else:
        ExistingValue += Adjustment
    return ExistingValue
"""

Exp = "Increment(!{0}!)".format(FieldA) # note the exclamation marks here

arcpy.CalculateField_management(YourData,OutField,Exp,"PYTHON",CodeBlock)
```